# Best way to model folder structure for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, data-structures

I need to create a file directory browser for a Ruby on Rails project and I'm having trouble to model the relationships.

Currently I have a folder model which has_many folders and belongs_to one folder. But I'm not sure how to assign parent folder to each when I'm creating these objects since I'm using information from an API and creating them recursively.

At first, I tried to have a children attribute for each folder with an array of folder objects but the objects in the array was saved as string and not a Folder type.

I read somewhere that I should probably use record association instead of nesting objects within each other. Does anyone have done something similar before and can give me suggestion on how to create an efficient model?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a simple tree-you can do it manually or use a gem. It's not clear what your specific issue is.

Comment: For some reason, the objects in the array are just a string representation of the object and not the object itself, so I can't access the object. Does ruby not allow a chain of objects?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You'll likely need to provide further information in the question body.

Comment: I think it might be a string because my schema is set up incorrectly. In schema.rb, can we do t.CustomModelType?

Comment: Can you please share the code that causes the issue?

Comment: You're trying to store an object in the database?

Comment: Ruby allows a "chain of objects". That's not what you're trying to do; you're creating a tree structure in an RDBMS. This is a different thing. Modeling trees ina relational DB is straight-forward, and gems to do this exist if you don't want to role your own. Creating it is the same as any other tree creation mechanism, except you're using AR models. This is searchable on the web, e.g., http://randycoulman.com/blog/2015/09/29/representing-trees-in-rails/.